# Eucalyptus Installation on Centos?

Tags: installation, centos, cloud, centos7, eucalyptus

How to install Eucalyptus on Centos 7 or higher versions?

[image: command line]

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with the FastStart install:

```
# bash <(curl -Ls https://get.eucalyptus.cloud)
```

you may want to give the [automated install](https://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/5/install_guide/automated_install/) a try.